# java GZIPOutputStream blocks ChunkedOutput http response

Tags: java, jersey, gzipoutputstream

I've written a basic REST Server using Jersey2 on top of Jetty, to test out HTTP Chunked Transfer-Encoding, and gzip Content-Encoding. However I've found that the recommended method of implementing a WriterInceptor to apply a GZIPOutputStream for gzip encoding results in the server blocking instead of sending through a gzip'd chunk.
I believe it is the GZIPOutputStream waiting for it's own buffer to fill up, so I tried overriding write() method in the WriterInterceptor to force a flush() after every write (as my server always writes one chunk at a time) but that made no difference. Is there a way of forcing the flush to occur whenever a write occurs?

**App.java**

```
public class App
{

    public static int lineCount=0;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.packages("com.example.mockAPIjava");
        ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));

        EncodingFilter.enableFor(config, GZipEncoder.class);

        Server server = new Server(2222);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/*");
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/*");


        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**GZIPWriterInterceptor.java**

```
@Provider
@Compress
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = context.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream) {
            @Override
            public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
                out.write(b);
                out.flush();
            }

            @Override
            public void write(final byte[] b) throws IOException {
                out.write(b);
                out.flush();
            }

            @Override
            public void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) throws IOException {
                out.write(b, off, len);
                out.flush();
            }
        });
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Resource.java**

```
@Path("stream")
public class Resource {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Compress
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ChunkedOutput<String> helloWorld(@Context HttpHeaders header, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        final ChunkedOutput<String> output = new ChunkedOutput<String>(String.class, "\r\n");

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader br = null;

                try {
                    String chunk;

                    // open file for reading
                    File file = new File("/tmp/stream.txt");
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    while ((chunk = getNextString(br)) != null) {
                        // write a chunk every second
                        output.write(chunk);

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // IOException thrown when writing the
                    // chunks of response: should be handled
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {        
                        output.close();
                        // simplified: IOException thrown from
                        // this close() should be handled here...
                        if (br!=null) { br.close(); }
                    } catch (IOException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        // the output will be probably returned even before
        // a first chunk is written by the new thread
        return output;
    }


    private String getNextString(BufferedReader br) throws IOException, ParseException {
        App.lineCount++;
        return br.readLine();;
    }
}
```

**Compress.java**

```
//@Compress annotation is the name binding annotation for the GZIPWriterInterceptor
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Compress {}
```

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the `write` methods of `GZIPOutputStream`, you have just stopped it from gzipping!

```
public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
    out.write(b);
    out.flush();
}
```

Because you've overridden it to *not* invoke `super.write` (which you should have done), but rather `out.write`, you're sending directly to the context OutputStream, uncompressed.

Presumably, the receiving side is expecting gzip data and not receiving it, which may lead to all kinds of wrong behaviour.

Change the code to invoke `super.write` and `flush`:

```
public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
    super.write(b);
    flush();
}
```

etc.

Comment: Ahh..thanks. I updated the code, but the behaviour hasn't changed. When I use curl to call the Server I receive the correct response headers and then the Server hangs until it closes the stream instead of sending each chunk as soon as it is written.
< Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 22:04:54 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)
<